# event subscription storage queue ARM template

Tags: azure, templates, arm

```
"resources": [
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('eventGridTopicName'), '/Microsoft.EventGrid/', parameters('eventGridSubscriptionName'))]",
            "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/providers/eventSubscriptions",
            "location": "France central",
            "apiVersion": "2018-01-01",
            "properties": {
                "destination": {
                    "endpointType": "StorageQueue",
                    "properties": {                 
                        "resourceId": "/subscriptions/57a94d8d-cece-4585-af8a-e0660dd3eeac/resourceGroups/APP-Integration-InterfaceEchange-RG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccounttestinteg",
                        "queueName":"testqueueintg"                     
                    }
                },
        "filter": {
            "advancedFilters": []
        },
        "labels": [],
        "eventDeliverySchema": "EventGridSchema"
        }
    }
]
```

this my resource to deploy event subscription but I got this error:

> | Resource Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/providers/eventSubscriptions
>        | 'Eventtopictest-Integration/Microsoft.EventGrid/EventSubcriptiontest-Integration'
>   failed with
>        | message '{   "error": {     "code": "InvalidRequest",     "message": "Invalid event subscription
>        | request: Supplied URL is invalid. It cannot be null or empty and should be a proper HTTPS URL like
>        | https://www.example.com."   } }'

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with one of your parameters. Can you show what parameters were used for this ARM? Ex. eventGridTopicName, eventGridSubscriptionName.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `2018-01-01` [API version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.eventgrid/2018-01-01/eventsubscriptions#eventsubscriptiondestination-object), which doesn't support the `StorageQueue` value.
[There is support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.eventgrid/2019-01-01/eventsubscriptions#eventsubscriptiondestination-object) from `2019-01-01` and beyond.